# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' при получении значения из словаря по ключу

Tags: python, коллекции, python-3.5

Существует словарь, где ключ - это строка, а значение - это список списков.
Вот пример:

```
'INMARSAT': [['IH0', 'N', 'M', 'AA1', 'R', 'S', 'AE1', 'T']]
```

При попытке создать новый словарь, ключом которого будет длина ключа предыдущего словаря, а значением - множество кортежа (ключ и значение предыдущего словаря). 
Пример:

```
1:{('INMARSAT',['IH0', 'N', 'M', 'AA1', 'R', 'S', 'AE1', 'T'])}
```

При таком коде:

```
        for items in dictionary:
        result_else[len(dictionary[items])] = set(tuple((str(items), dictionary[items])))
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rostykpopov/Documents/ucu/dict_task.py", line 49, in <module>
print(dict_invert(dict_reader_tuple('cmudict.txt')))
File "/Users/rostykpopov/Documents/ucu/dict_task.py", line 41, in      dict_invert
result_else[len(result[items])] = set(tuple((str(items), result[items])))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Что не так?

Comment: Приведите полный traceback. Разбейте код на несколько строчек, чтобы было ясно какое выражение исключение выбрасывает.

Comment: не понял
что именно сделать?

Comment: Найдите место где вы увидели слово TypeError на экране, поднимайтесь пока не увидите слово traceback, скопируйте все строчки и вставьте в вопрос. Если не очевидно какое именно выражение ответственно за ошибку, то вычисляйте результат в несколько шагов, вместо того чтобы всё в одну строчку помещать (поместите `value = result[items]` на отдельную строку в коде).

Comment: ещо чтото?или достаточно?

Comment: Очевидно какое именно выражение ответственно за ошибку?

Comment: не хочет сделать список значением словаря насколько я понимаю

Comment: Мой комментарий это намёк что вам следует строку кода на несколько разделить.

Comment: не понимаю как и что именно ти хочеш, сори

Comment: Кортеж может состоять только из hashable значений,  вы же в него список пытаетесь впихнуть.

Comment: @Vitalts слово "кортеж" обычно используют для перевода tuple, которая свободно может содержать списки. Вы вероятно имеете ввиду "набор/множество" (set). Из примера в вопросе не очевидно какое именно выражение исключение вызывает (и у автора сложности разбить одну строку кода на несколько, чтобы было ясно что исключение выбрасывает).

Comment: @Vitalts вы неверно понимаете как tuple работает в Питоне. Попробуйте задать отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос о том могут ли списки в tuple находится (я думаю, не у вас одного подобное заблуждение может быть) и заодно ответить (проверить легко: `([],)`, если можете ещё объяснение добавьте).

Comment: @jfs, проехали, пятница, туплю, осознал косяк и грохнул свой комментарий, похоже, в этот момент вы уже писали свой:)

Answer (score 2):

**Code:**

```
dictionary = {'INMARSAT': [['IH0', 'N', 'M', 'AA1', 'R', 'S', 'AE1', 'T']]}
result_else = dict()

for items in dictionary:
    result_else[len(items)] = dictionary

print(result_else)
```

**Result:**

```
{8: {'INMARSAT': [['IH0', 'N', 'M', 'AA1', 'R', 'S', 'AE1', 'T']]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

В set не могут находиться изменяемые елементы(`list` например), так  что "значением - множество кортежа (ключ и значение предыдущего словаря)" не выполнимо.

Но можно так:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    result_else[len(value)] = (key, value)
```

То есть просто кортеж, а не множество. Если хотите множество, то надо свой класс `list` или `set` делать.